# How to recognize firebase dynamic link before addSuccesListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

In my application, many link handled in same Activity,

So, I need to know what link when link received.

I know that I will recognize after success listener,

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(intent)
                .addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            Uri deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
```

but, My app's UI thread have to know before success listener, because of UI thread's next operations.

So, I handle intent like that,

```
if(intent.getExtras() != null
            && intent.getExtras().toString().contains("firebase")) { // this comes from firebase dynamic links.
```

Could I handle intent in this way?
And, Firebase framework will aways put extra data include firebase string?

Could you please, let me know any other solution?
The bast ways, I hope to know my apps' host "(app).goo.gl" before success callback..

Comment: Bundle Data like that,  B@hashcode aways changed, So I using toString().contains("firebase")
Bundle[{com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.DYNAMIC_LINK_DATA=[B@c5ac3a7, com.google.android.gms.appinvite.REFERRAL_BUNDLE=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=456]}]

Comment: I don't believe there is a better way than the approach you've outlined. That said, the best approach would be if you could wait on your dependent UI operations - what prevents putting them in a completion listener?

Comment: @심현용 Did you find more reliable solution for that?

Comment: @dor506 check this article https://deepakdroid.medium.com/firebase-recognize-fdl-before-onsuccesslistener-81e187a9b8dd. I used this approach in my app.

Answer (score 7):

You can check if intent extras contains special constant

```
getIntent().hasExtra("com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.DYNAMIC_LINK_DATA")
```

Comment: https://deepakdroid.medium.com/firebase-recognize-fdl-before-onsuccesslistener-81e187a9b8dd

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is actually incorrect. The correct way to check for Firebase Dynamic link is to look inside `getIntent().getData()`. This will contain a Uri when app is opened via a Firebase Dynamic Link